# How to create a 'has_many through' association if a polymorphic association is involved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have 4 models: Model 1 associated with model 2, and model 2 with model 3. Models 2 and 3 are associated to model 4 with a polymorphic association. This all works. I'm having trouble specifying the association between model 1 and model 4, which are thus related in two ways:

1. model 1 - model 2 - model 4
2. model 1 - model 2 - model 3 - model 4

Below you'll find all the associations, except that between model 1 and model 4:

---

Author model:

```
has_many :books,     dependent: :destroy
```

Book model:

```
belongs_to :author
has_many   :chapters, dependent: :destroy
has_many   :titles,   as: :titlesource,       # Polymorphic Association
                      dependent: :destroy
```

Chapter model:

```
belongs_to :book
has_many   :titles,   as: :titlesource,       # Polymorphic Association
                      dependent: :destroy
```

Title model:

```
belongs_to :titlesource, polymorphic: true
```

---

**Question:** Suppose you have the above associations and you want to know the `titles` that an `author` has, irrespective whether they are a book-title or chapter-title. What associations should I expand the above setup with? (I assume something with `has_many through`)

*Update:* If it were only book-titles I would be looking for, I would expect adding `has_many :titles, through: :books` to the `Author` model to work. But it doesn't. If I add that association, then `Author.first.titles` produces the error `undefined method 'titles'`. I think this has to do with the polymorphic association and naming...? What am I doing wrong?

For chapter title it is even more difficult. That association goes through the `Book` model, then through the `Chapter` model and then to the `Title` model. How can I include these titles in the author model? I think it would have to be code with the following logic (but obviously this code is incorrect):

```
has_many :titles, through: :books && :books:chapters
```

**Update:** The two answers given use SQL. Do these solutions not send a lot of queries to the db, causing problems if the method is used often? Has one of these methods an advantage over the other in performance?

Comment: not get totally but `book has many chapters` `chapters has many titles` this way now from book you can includes titles by `Book.include({:chapters => :titles})`

Comment: Not sure that's what I'm looking for. I would want a list of all `titles` for an `author`. A `title` either has a relationship with a `book` or a `chapter`, But `chapter` has no direction relationship with `author` as such goes through `book`.

Comment: so this for 1st author titles  `Author.first.books.map(&:titles)`

Comment: @RajarshiDas expand it =)

Comment: `has_many :books, -> {includes :titles}` on the author now it will load the books with titles

Comment: try something like: `has_many :titles, -> { |author| author.books.titles.merge(author.books.chapters.titles) }`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ if in author model we do `has_many :titles, through: :books ` Then?

Comment: @RajarshiDas then it selects only book titles =)

Comment: yes  he want chapters also ? :=))

Comment: Thanks, yes I'd like all titles for an author. I've tried `has_many :titles, -> { |author| author.books.titles.merge(author.books.chapters.titles) }`. If in the console I enter `Author.first` I get the error: `syntax error, unexpected '|'` referring to the added association line.

Comment: I rewrote it as `has_many :titles do |author|` ; `author.books.titles.merge(author.books.chapters.titles)` ; `end`. Then if I enter `Author.first` I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'books'`.

Comment: `has_many :titles, ->(author) { author.books.titles.merge(author.books.chapters.titles) }`

Comment: you can try two asscoication `has_many :titles, through: :books`, and `has_many :chapter_titles, through: :chapters, class: 'Chapter` and `has_many :chapters, through: :books` now in console `Author.titles & Author.chapter_titles`

Comment: @Малъ, `aut=Author.first` ; `aut.titles` in the console produces the error: `undefined method 'titles'`. If I going step-by-step it goes without errors: `aut=Author.first` ; `book=aut.books.first` ; `chapter=book.chapters.first` ; `chapter.titles`.  @Rajarshi, this produces the error `Could not find the association :chapter_titles in model Author` (I think setting it up like this requires also an association between `Author` and `Chapter`).

Comment: can you just collect all the title in such way `author.books.titles` directly in code (not as a scope)?

Comment: No, I get the same error that `books` is undefined method. It does work if I change it to `author.books.first.titles` (and then of course only shows one book title). Also if I add `has_many :titles, through: :books` to the model file, it doesn't work. I've also tried `author.books.titlesource(s)` (plural and singular) and that didn't work either.

Comment: A suggestion, if you need a bounty on SO to make a complex combination of metamagic functions in a bloated metamagic framework work as expected, then only imagine what you'll see in production :D I like Reykos raw sql approach in this even though I didn't verify if it actually works ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to use an association on the `Author` like `has_many :titles, through: :books` it should normally work as long as you have set a `titlesource_id` and a `titlesource_type` on the `Title` model migration.

However, if you would add another one to fetch the titles through the chapters like this `has_many :titles, through: :chapters` it would overwrite the first one and it would fetch only the titles that are of `titlesource_type = 'Chapter'`.

Therefore the solution that I would suggest to you, if you don't mind sql is to implement a method like this in the Author model.

```
  def titles
    Title.where(
      "(titles.titlesource_type = 'Book'
      AND titles.titlesource_id
      IN (SELECT books.id FROM books WHERE books.author_id = #{id}))
      OR (titles.titlesource_type = 'Chapter'
      AND titles.titlesource_id
      IN (SELECT chapters.id
      FROM books
      INNER JOIN chapters ON chapters.book_id = books.id
      WHERE books.author_id = #{id}))"
    )
  end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this produce a lot of db queries?

Comment: @Marty In the console you will see one query but that query contains two nested queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need ActiveRecord methods (like `where` or `order`), then this will give you an array of titles.

```
def titles_array  # sacrificing ActiveRecord methods
  books.collect { |b| b.titles + b.chapters.collect { |c| c.titles } }
end
```

You can still use AR methods on the individual array elements such as `titles_array.first.author`, etc